# How to install package keras in R

Tags: r, installation, keras

I'm trying to install deep learning package `keras` on RStudio using this [website](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/09/05/keras-for-r/). I installed `keras` using

```
install.packages("keras") 
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

but when I tried to open the `MNIST` dataset

`mnist <- dataset_mnist()`

I keep getting the error

> Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'absl'

I thought keras installed tensorflow but do I need to install tensorflow separately?

Comment: Try install.packages("keras", dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: good idea, but it didn't work - same error message

Comment: Did you try `pip install absl-py`, you need `absl-py >= 0.1.6` [check the link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a12e9f4425018ffae403a0ee8ec24187b4d52897/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L34-L43)

Comment: So try `devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")`?

Comment: @AaghazHussain RStudio didn't recognize the command ``pip install absl-py`` - so that didn't work

Comment: @Tung I ran ``devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")`` successfully but that also didn't fix the problem

Comment: If I were you, I would just give up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and it is solved by installing the package in two steps:

```
install keras: install.packages("keras")
keras::install_keras()
```

There you go!

Comment: I still get this `> mnist<- dataset_mnist()
ImportError: No module named keras`

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the TUT and still got error, try running `py_config()` and check the python and libpython if it is pointing to an r-tensorflow environment. If not, best to try manually install keras in your manually set up conda environment.

### Step 1: Install keras in your R just like in the link above.

```
#Open rstudio and run the following command
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras") 
#Don't close rstudio after running this, okay?
```

### Step 2: Manually install keras (and tensorflow) in your machine ##. When i say “manual” it means using python specifically through conda. Here’s the link I followed: https://medium.com/i-want-to-be-the-very-best/installing-keras-tensorflow-using-anaconda-for-machine-learning-44ab28ff39cb .

In summary, the link will teach you to install anaconda, create an environment and install necessary libraries. Just follow it. I named my environment as “r-tensorflow” because that is the name of the environment that the install_keras() in R will do :)

### Step 3: Point rstudio to use the python in your newly created environment using use_python() function

Open your rstudio (if you close it after following step 1) and type the following code

```
library(keras)
library(reticulate)
# in case you run into error run this : reticulate::py_discover_config("keras") 
use_python("<yourpath>/Anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/Scripts/python.exe")
# change <yourpath> approriately
# write all the codes for building model in keras (or tensorflow) e.g. mnist<-dataset_mnist()
```

Important note on **Step 3:** If you still got the "not found module" after following step 3, you must start a new fresh R session and ensure to delete the workspace (.RData) because more likely your current script will still use the old python configuration though you used use_python

Comment: Works like charm

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but mine was solved by enclosing `keras` in double quotes.

```
    install.packages("keras")    ## worked for me, 

    install.packages(keras)      ## never worked.
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
    install.packages("devtools")
    devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
    library(keras)
    mnist<-dataset_mnist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please install "reticulate" library using command `install.packages("reticulate")` and then load using `library(reticulate)`
then install absl using command
`conda_install('r-tensorflow','absl-py')`

Comment: I ran all three commands successfully, but I now have another error... 
 ``Error: Python module keras was not found.``
So still no fix

Comment: I closed and reopened the project, loaded the reticulate library, but I still get the original error saying no absl module found

Answer (score 0):

For me it was really like @pari said in the accepted answer but in addition I had to force the default Python version to downgrade (3.12 -> 3.9).

```
install.packages("keras")
install_keras(python_version = "3.9")
```

It is confusing that this keyword argument does not appear in the [official doc](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/reference/keras/install_keras) but only in the `tensorflow::install_tensorflow` doc