# GETTING ERROR WHILE EXECUTING THE COMMAND install_keras() in R studio

Tags: r, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I was trying to run the command install_keras() in R Studio but it is showing error. how to resolve this issue kindly help.

> Error:installing python packages into virtualenv is not supported on windows

[image]

Comment: Do you have python installed? Maybe [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684605/how-to-install-package-keras-in-r) and [this](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-setup-keras-and-tensorflow-in-rstudio-on-windows-d0175e9a8f10) helps you further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install package keras in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684605/how-to-install-package-keras-in-r)